# SQL Average Time from timestamp stored as string

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, group-by, average

I have two columns called `date` and `starthour` in a Microsoft SQL Server table.

Both columns are char; Another guy make it and I don't know why it was built in this way. :)

```
date                     starthour

20/01/2011               8:10:00
20/01/2011               8:20:00
20/01/2011               8:30:00
20/01/2011               8:40:00
21/01/2011               8:10:00
21/01/2011               8:20:00
21/01/2011               8:30:00
```

I want to determine the average `starthour` for each date.

```
date                     starthour
20/01/2011               8:25:00
21/01/2011               8:20:00
```

I tried the following:

```
SELECT date, Avg(cast(starhour as datetime())) AS starhour
FROM table
GROUP BY date
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: The answer to this may depend on which database engine you are using. Could you update your question to mention this? Also, it looks like your starthour column is a TIME rather than a DATETIME, since it doesn't include a date component.

Comment: I am using SQL server, really starthour is only a char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's not beat around the bush: you should fix this schema as soon as possible.

In the meantime, this will return the correct value.

```
select [date], 
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), 
 cast((avg(cast(cast(starhour as datetime)  as float)))   as datetime) , 108)
  from table
group by [date]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT [date], 
  CAST(DATEADD(second, AVG(DATEDIFF(second, 0 , starhour)), '00:00:00') AS time)
FROM dbo.test17
GROUP BY [date]
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/de37f/1)

Answer (score 1):

**Do not store dates, datetimes or timestamps as varchar.** For instance, MySQL has native types for all three of these types, which guarantees that you won't have invalid data in them, and that MySQL will know how to treat them: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

What you should do is have a single field, `date`, that is of `timestamp` type, containing both the date and the time. You should refactor your database and transfer over all your data to the new format by casting it, so that you never have to worry about again.

After that what you need to do differs based on your SQL flavour. For example, this answer will be for MySQL, but every flavour has different datetime functions (unfortunately!).

MySQL's datetime functions are http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Untested but something like:

`GROUP BY EXTRACT(day from date)`

`AVG(EXTRACT(hour from date)*60 + EXTRACT(minute from date))`